# Android notification not vibrating if phone is in call

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have tested that normally when i create the notification phone is vibrating but during a phone call it just play a sound but not vibrating any solution OR can we make notification to force vibrate in any situation if by default vibration is not allow from OS side?
Here is my code:

```
 private final long[] vibration_pattern = new long[]{0, 700, 200, 100, 100, 600, 200, 100, 100, 600, 200, 100, 100, 900};

 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(zone)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 1, intent, 0))
                .setVibrate(vibration_pattern);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId++, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: why would you want user be angry :D maybe android prevent it purposely

Comment: Did you try to use PhoneStateListener ? Maybe you can force vibration when phone is on call state.

Comment: Find an alternative as notification vibration is not work during a phone call we can do normal vibration like:  Vibrator v = (Vibrator) mContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(500);